# R diagrammer package not recognizing tenth footnote

Tags: r, diagrammer

I have noticed that I am getting errors in my footnote interpretations over the last week or so. I tried updating to the latest version as well as the latest github download. I have also updated R and R studio to the latest versions.

Starting with footnote 10, there is a misinterpretation of the previously outlined labels:

```
grViz("
digraph {
graph [layout = dot]
node [shape = box, fontname = Helvetica]
a [label = '@@1']
b [label = '@@2']
c [label = '@@3']
d [label = '@@4']
e [label = '@@5']
f [label = '@@6']
g [label = '@@7']
h [label = '@@8']
i [label = '@@9']
j [label = '@@10']
k [label = '@@11']
l [label = '@@12']
m [label = '@@13']
n [label = '@@14']
o [label = '@@15']
p [label = '@@16']

a -> {b c d}
b -> {e f}
c -> {g h}
d -> {i j}
e -> {k}
f -> {l}
g -> {m}
h -> {n}
i -> {o}
j -> {p}

}

[1]: 'hello'
[2]: 'there'
[3]: 'how'
[4]: 'are'
[5]: 'you'
[6]: 'today'
[7]: 7
[8]: 8
[9]: 9
[10]: 'this one is interpreted as @@1 + 0 rather than @@10'
[11]: 'this one is interpreted as @@1 + 1 rather than @@11'
[12]: 'etc'
[13]: 'etc'
[14]: 'etc'
[15]: 'etc'
[16]: 'etc'
")
```

[image: diagrammer plot]

Answer (score 0):

This way of writing the substitution works. Each level in the diagram gets its own hyphenated series.

```
grViz("
digraph boxes_and_circles {

# several 'node' statements
  node [shape = box, color = tomato,
        fontname = Helvetica]
  a ; b ; c1 ; c2 ; d1 ; d2 ; d3 ; d4 ; e1 ; e2 ; e3 ; e4 ; e5 ; e6 ; e7 ; e8

# 'edge' statements
  a->b->{c1,c2} c1->{d1,d2} c2->{d3,d4} d1->{e1,e2} d2->{e3,e4} d3->{e5,e6} d4->{e7,e8}


# a 'graph' statement
  graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]
a [label = 'Enrolled\nN=@@1']
b [label = 'Randomized\nN=@@2']
c1 [label = '15-Day\nN=@@3-1']
c2 [label = '60-Day\nN=@@3-2']
d1 [label = 'WGS\nPositive\nN=@@4-1']
d2 [label = 'WGS\nNegative\nN=@@4-2']
d3 [label = 'WGS\nPositive\nN=@@4-3']
d4 [label = 'WGS\nNegative\nN=@@4-4']
e1 [label = 'Visit3 COM\nTRUE\nN=@@5-1']
e2 [label = 'Visit3 COM\nFALSE\nN=@@5-2']
e3 [label = 'Visit3 COM\nTRUE\nN=@@5-3']
e4 [label = 'Visit3 COM\nFALSE\nN=@@5-4']
e5 [label = 'Visit3 COM\nTRUE\nN=@@5-5']
e6 [label = 'Visit3 COM\nFALSE\nN=@@5-6']
e7 [label = 'Visit3 COM\nTRUE\nN=@@5-7']
e8 [label = 'Visit3 COM\nFALSE\nN=@@5-8']

}

[1]: A
[2]: B
[3]: c(C1,C2)
[4]: c(D1,D2,D3,D4)
[5]: c(E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8)


")
```